# Ajax invoking PHP object function

Tags: wordpress

I have a class called `xyz`. And a member function `wp_xyz_func()`, which will be called through shortcode of wordpress.

```
// add shortcode handler
add_shortcode ( 'list-view', array ( &$this, 'wp_xyz_func' ) );
```

`wp_xyz_func()`, this function lists posts along with pagination.

I want to dynamically update posts using AJAX using `$.ajax({})`. Now how to invoke `wp_xyz_func()` ?

Comment: Create a ajax page like ajax.php and give the url of ajax.php in $.ajax({url: 'ajax.php url'}); In ajax.php, include the file in which your class xyz is there using include_once or require_once function. Then create a instance of class ex: $obj and call the member function $obj->wp_xyz_func();

Comment: Is it possible to invoke without creating instance of class ? somethink like passing pointer of already existing class ?

Comment: No. AJAX makes requests to a URL, like any other URL you type in the browser. You cannot make calls to functions directly.

Comment: BTW what is the URL we need to pass ? because wp_xyz_func() is added using add_shortcode ( 'list-view', array ( &$this, 'wp_xyz_func' ) );

Comment: Create a page that displays the information you want when you type its URL into the browser's address bar. Then call that URL via AJAX. I have no idea how much code exactly needs to go into that page since I don't know Wordpress.